# Updating row column with count value of query in same table

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I was wondering if somebody could help.

I have a products table and in the table a column called master_colours.

I have 3 columns in the table called stock_id, master and colour, the master column tells it which stock_id to link to like so...

```
stock_id, master, colour
12345, '', ''
aaa, '12345', 'red'
bbb, '12345', 'blue'
ccc, '12345', 'green'
```

In the master_colours column I want it to be updated to the value of how many colours the master product will have so in the example above it will be 3.

I have so far the following code which returns the error #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row.

```
UPDATE products AS main
SET main.master_colours = (SELECT master.stock_id FROM (
SELECT p.stock_id, COUNT(DISTINCT(m.colour))
FROM products AS p, products AS m
WHERE m.master = p.stock_id AND m.colour != ''
GROUP BY p.stock_id) AS master)
```

I understand why it is doing it because I have grouped by the stock_id but if I dont do this then it counts all colours in the table rather than the colours linked to that stock id.

The logical thing to me would be to do this...

```
UPDATE products AS main
SET main.master_colours = (SELECT master.stock_id FROM (
SELECT p.stock_id, COUNT(DISTINCT(m.colour))
FROM products AS p, products AS m
WHERE m.master = p.stock_id AND m.colour != '' AND p.stock_id = main.stock_id
GROUP BY p.stock_id) AS master)
```

but obviously this doesnt work because main.stock_id is outside the sub query.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide correct schema of products table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
UPDATE products p JOIN
(
  SELECT master, COUNT(*) total
    FROM products
   GROUP BY master
) q ON p.stock_id = q.master
   SET p.master_colours = total;
```

*That is assuming that you only have 1 level deep hierarchy*

Outcome:

```
| STOCK_ID | MASTER | COLOUR | MASTER_COLOURS |
|----------|--------|--------|----------------|
|    12345 |        |        |              3 |
|      aaa |  12345 |    red |         (null) |
|      bbb |  12345 |   blue |         (null) |
|      ccc |  12345 |  green |         (null) |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ebe8/1)** demo